# Reading blocks of text in perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to break a page of text into blocks based on a start and end string. I saw a posting on how to do this but for some reason (probably something wrong between the keybd and the chair), I'm not getting any returned rows.

This is that I have so far:

```
open INPUT, "in.file" || die "Can't find file\n";
open OUT, ">log.out" || die "Can't opne file\n";


$start="\/\*";
$stop= "\/\=";
$found=0;

while (<INPUT>) 
 {
 if (/$start/ .. /$stop/) 
  {
  next if /$start/ || /$stop/;
  if ($found == 0)
   {
   print "NOT FOUND\n";
   }
  else
   {
   print "FOUND\n";
   }
  }
 }
```

We'll use this as an example of what I'm reading in:

/*  Batch process 1 - abc
...
..
.
/=

/* Batch process 2 - jkl
...
..
.
/=

/* Batch process 3 - xyz
...
..
.
/=

Before anyone comments, yes I am a newbie at programming in general so apologies for simple errors here. I did go on line and check for samples but to no avail. Again apologies if this this is an elementary question.

Answer (score 2):

You have an order of operations issue in the first line (as well as using a global filehandle rather than a local lexical). Change those statements to:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $input, 'in.file' or die "Can't find file\n";
open my $out, '>', 'log.out' or die "Can't open file\n";
```

Also, you're checking the `$found` variable, but never setting it (don't forget to clear it again at the top of each loop iteration).

Otherwise, your code looks okay, although you could simplify your regexes a bit for readability:

```
my $start = '/*';
my $end = '/=';

# ... and inside the loop:
$found = 1 if /\Q$start\E/ .. /\Q$stop\E/;
```

Comment: Actually I think your second change is what makes the difference. Pay attention in the original, there's double-interpolation, so at the point where it matters, the `*` isn't backslashed :)